# Firefox plugins - uMatrix vs Policeman

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I've used both plugins (independently of each other) off and on the last year or so and I'm trying to understand the differences between them; specifically how "scopes" work.

In [Policeman](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/policeman/), there are a number of sites under Origin.  I have the impression that if site A loads site Y, site B loads site Y, and site Y loads site Z, if I configure rules for site Y about site Z they apply when sites A and B load site Y.

In [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/) the blue box specifies scope, which appears to be global, site.com, specific.site.com, and the like.  This seems different from how Policeman works.

My common use case example is youtube - I want to configure everything once for youtube (site Y) relative to ytimg, googlevideo (sites Z) and the like.  Can both extensions handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer in [this issue](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/issues/645) it's not capable and he's not willing to add the feature.

To get part of the way there ([source](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/support-umatrix/5131/6)), add the following rules:

```
* ytimg.com * allow
* googlevideo.com * allow
```

then allow youtube.com (with frames) on the particular site(s) you want.